# Have two tabs in ejs, when i go back to the original tab it stays on the second, any advice appreciated

Tags: javascript, css, sql, ejs

guys so got stuck a bit, working on a program for a database class and have a pesky problem that I can't seem to resolve. So when I go into the products page, I have 2 tabs, products and a list of products. When I enter the page I'm on the products tab and I can add in the product without any issue. However, when I switch to the tab that has the list of products and then try to go back to the products tab it stays stuck on the list of products even though it highlights the products tab.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs  tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#productos" role="tab">Productos</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#lis_productos" role="tab">Lista de Productos</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content tabs card-block">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="reg_producto" role="tabpanel">
        <form action="/registrar_producto" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="codigo_producto">Código de Producto</label>
                <input type="codigo_producto" id="codigo_producto" name="codigo_producto" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Digite un código de producto"
                    value="<%= typeof codigo_producto != 'undefined' ? codigo_producto : '' %>" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre_producto">Nombre de Producto</label>
                <input type="nombre_producto" id="nombre_producto" name="nombre_producto" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Confirme Nombre de Producto"
                    value="<%= typeof nombre_producto != 'undefined' ? nombre_producto : '' %>" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
                <input type="descripcion" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Entra descripcion 150 caracteres o menos"
                    value="<%= typeof descripcion != 'undefined' ? descripcion : '' %>" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                Añadir Producto
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="lis_productos" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="dt-responsive table-responsive">
            <table id="simpletable" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your href must reference the id of the tab you want to activate

Try changing to:

```
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#reg_producto" role="tab">Productos</a>
</li>
```

Comment: wow thanks, i spent hours thinking i had made some mistake with the script code and it was right in front of me.. thanks